# Spring Security Java configuration without Spring/Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-security, tomcat6

There are a few similar looking questions in stackoverflow, but none of them seems to answer it clearly.

I'm adding Spring Security to an existing web application which doesn't use Spring or Spring MVC. I only need the Spring Security filter, and nothing else (no MVC etc). My XML based configuration works perfectly fine, but not the Java configuration. I was mostly following [this guide](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-without-existing-spring). For some reason the Spring Security filter doesn't seem to be available.

So the security configuration is as below - `SecurityConfig.java`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

And the `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java`

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong above? How does the `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` gets initialized and load the security config? Is the initialization part of the servlet context loading - which I have to explicitly define somewhere?

Comment: @user30622 Are you using Servlet 3+? As WebApplicationInitializer will only work with that or above. And what your Web Server? Tomcat?

Comment: @shazin yes, I'm using servlet api 3.0.1. FYI, I also  use jersey for jax-rs. I hope that shouldn't be a problem as everything works perfectly fine with xml based configuration. Problem shows up when switching java based config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat 6 doesn't support Servlet API 3+, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat#Releases):

> First Apache Tomcat release to support the Servlet 2.5, JSP 2.1, and EL 2.1 specifications.

You need a container with Servlet API 3+, see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer):

> The next step is to register the `springSecurityFilterChain` with the war. This can be done in Java Configuration with Spring’s WebApplicationInitializer support in a Servlet 3.0+ environment.

You could use Tomcat 7 (or higher), see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat#Releases):

> First Apache Tomcat release to support the Servlet 3.0, JSP 2.2, and EL 2.2 specifications.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the SecurityWebApplicationInitializer gets initialized and load the security config ?

From the guide:

- Add a ContextLoaderListener that loads the WebSecurityConfig.

This listener is responsible for initializing the configuration. It should be someting like:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The listener will load applicationContext.xml which should contain a component-scan where to find your beans, e.g.:

```
<beans ...>
     <context:component-scan base-package="your.package.here"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: The guide says, `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` will do that, which I already have. Then the question is, what is wrong above that wouldn't work ?

Comment: @ike3 No need to have <listener> tag as the whole purpose of is to load the Context AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer without web.xml configuration

Comment: @ike3 , added `applicatonContext.xml` and now the errors are gone, but the security filter is still not present. :( Here's my `applicationContext.xml` http://pastebin.com/X7imr8Nq